# Unable to connect AWS using SFTP in notepad++

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can anyone help me how i connect to aws using sftp in notepad++.
I am able to connect to aws using sftp in filezilla and putty using .ppk file but i get this error when i try to connect with notepad++

- [NppFTP] Everything initialized Connecting
- [SFTP] Host key written to file
- [SFTP] Error during authentication: Access denied. Authentication
      that can continue: publickey
- Unable to connect
- Disconnected

Comment: Did you set the username in N++? I've seen that when I forget the username, eg. `ec2-user`

Comment: yes i add host name and username.

Comment: Then maybe you didn't configured N++ to use the right private key?